# Problem with android Studio with run a Flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

After a update made few month ago, it's no more possible to run a Flutter project on a virtual or physical device. it appears the following failture message:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 29 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What can I do tho solve this problem? I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Answer (score 0):

try writing this commands in powershell:

```
setx PUB_HOSTED_URL "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"

setx FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL "https://storage.flutter-io.cn"
```

it adds environment variables